# filter in Django

Tags: python, django, filter

Please help with my project.
I need filter my objects in the range date.
I'm try :

```
problems_filter = Data.objects.filter(
                                main_id=1
                              ).filter(
                                date__range=['data_date', 'end_date']
                              ).order_by(
                                 '-data_date'
                              ).order_by('priority')[:10]
```

but have error :

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'date' into field.
```

What the problem? can anybody help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `date` field defined on a `Data` model.

Looks like the field you need is called `data_date`:

```
problems_filter = Data.objects.filter(main_id=1).filter(data_date__range=["2011-01-01", "2011-01-31"]).order_by('-data_date').order_by('priority')[:10]
```

Also, make sure you have dates in the range list.